# magento custom price change like configurable product

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have a project same as bluestone.com. in this project product price vary with custom option select. i need same. you can see example here http://www.bluestone.com/rings/atlantis-ring~436.html .Its working like configurable product. can it is possible by configurable product?. I don't know the right way to perform this. if there are any extension for it i can purchase. or we can do this other way?. please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.There is two options to do this.

**option 1 :**
Simple product with custom options.
you can ass custom options with the price changed=s. once the customer select the option it will add the price to the content.

[image]

**Option 2 :**
Create configurable products with associated products.
you can set different prices for associated products

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be possible using a configurable product. You can assign fixed price in the associated product tab under a configurable product.